# Connect to Remote Oracle database from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g

My course requires me to connect to an Oracle database server at the university for my project. I am provided with a url (like oracle.xyz.edu) and username and password. How can I connect to the database from Visual Studio. I have only dealt with SQL Server 2008. I don't know how to go ahead with setting up the database. I tried to install Oracle Instant Client, but could not find a setup exe to install. The instant client download zip consists of a set of files. Where can I find the steps to connect to Oracle database from VS.

[image]

Comment: What part of that message is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use the Oracle Instant Client?  Or would it be acceptable to you to download and install the full version of the Oracle client?

The full version of the Oracle client is generally what ought to be installed on a developer machine.  The Instant Client is a very slimmed down version of the client that is designed for developers to distribute along with their Windows applications on machines that do not have or need any way to access the database other than via the application.  As a developer, I'd strongly recommend the full version of the Oracle client if only because it includes various additional utilities like SQL*Plus and SQL*Loader.

The full Oracle client is available for download from OTN on the same page that the database is available.  For example, the [Oracle 11.2 client for 64-bit Windows](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html) is a 615 MB download on the OTN site.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ODBC. Use [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) (Oracle's Instant Client) Oracle Data Provider for .NET. (Read technical notes in provided link.)